# Plot an Archimedean spiral using integer values with ggplot2

Tags: r, math, plot, ggplot2, spiral

How do you draw a swirl in R ?  I am trying to plot a list of numbers 1:100
and every 7th number assign it a factor '1' all others just '0' . I also have a vector of TRUE or FALSE . How do I plot a swirl of these numbers and highlight every seventh number ? Trying to see if I can tighten or loosen the swirl (theta) to align the 7th numbers. The following code I used to create the data. I used two different functions just to see which vector would work best. A logical vector or a vector of "1" or "0" 's .

```
returnint  <- function( x ) { 
if ( x == TRUE) {
        return (1)
    } else {
        return (0)
   }  
}

isseven <- function( x ) {
if  (x %% 7)  {
       return (0) # FALSE
    } else {
       return (1) # TRUE
   }
}

fo = seq(1, 100)
fo.sev = NULL # factors
fo.int = NULL   # as int 0 = FALSE , 1 = TRUE

for (i in 1:length(fo)) {
   fo.sev[i] = as.logical(isseven(i)) 
   fo.int[i] = returnint(fo.sev[i])
}


df <- data.frame(fo,fo.int,as.factor(fo.sev))
names(df) <- c("x","intx","seven")
df
```

Comment: closest I can come to plotting using polar coordinates is the following

Comment: [code link](http://pastebin.com/f2rsmJ0Q)

Comment: equation is here [link](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/spiral22.gif)  sorry about all these smaller bits , can't edit original post

Comment: Both equations using ggplot worked out [view](http://imgur.com/a/IIjN9) , but it plotted all the points , I am looking to plot the 7,14,21, 28, 35 , 42 ... etc . These would be superimposed on the swirl. Even If I could just plot the fo.sev vector I would be done.   THANKS!

Comment: You should use [edit] to explain more completely what you mean by the "plot" those numbers and the "swirl". Presumably you wnat the 7,14,etc to assume the role of x (or y) but are not explaining what the y (or x) should be. Several people have attempted mind-reading R packages but all have failed.

Answer (score 4):

(I admit to answering the request in the title, but not understanding what the rest of your text was requesting, although I later took a guess.) Just set up data with a pair of parametric equations:

```
x = t*cos(t); y = t*sin(t)
```

You need to instantiate `t` finely enough ... if your purpose is a smooth curve:

```
 t <- seq(0, 10, by=0.01)
 x = t*cos(t); y = t*sin(t)
 ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_path()
```

[image]

This is a guess at what was requested for plotting the integers;

```
png()
  print( ggplot( df, aes(x=x*cos(x), y=x*sin(x)))  + 
            geom_label(data=df, aes(label=x, color=intx, size=intx + 1) ) + 
            coord_equal() )
  dev.off()
```

[image]

It did appear that the label boxes had a minimum size, since they appeared visible even when their `size` was zero. And I did get smaller "label boxes" with `label.padding = unit(0.05, "lines")`

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for -- Thanks, I really want to plot with finer detail so will have to see if I can get this to go to 100 maybe or pixelate it with openGL, now that I know its possible

Answer (score 3):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral, the polar equation of an Archimedian Spiral is `r=a+b*theta`, with real numbers a and b. The following code can be used to draw one:

```
# for some fixed real a, b
a <- 2
b <- 3
theta <- seq(0,10*pi,0.01)
r <- a + b*theta
df <- data.frame(x=r*cos(theta), y=r*sin(theta)) # Cartesian coords
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(col='red')
```

[image]